# Preventing usbhid from claiming device

Tags: linux, drivers, usb, packaging

In order for my USB driver's _probe function to be called, I need to prevent usbhid from claiming it first. To do this I wrote a UDEV rule which unbinds the device.

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVER=="usbhid", ATTRS{idVendor}=="ffff",
>   ATTRS{idProduct}=="ffff", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n $id:1.0 >
>   /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind'"

While this works, what is the standard practice for distributing drivers? Do I have to also package this rule? Is there any way for my own driver to take priority over usbhid?

Comment: Since this is more of a driver programming question, it might be better placed on Stack Overflow, or in a hardware_development.SE if one exists.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel selects the drivers for each device based on the `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE`s. The HID device table is considered more specific than the generic USB device table, so if your device claims USB HID device class, then your driver should probably include a HID class MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE too.

The matching algorithm favors specific matches over generic class-based ones, so if your device table entry includes some USB or HID device attributes unique to it, your driver should get priority over the generic `usbhid` driver.

If your idVendor and idProduct identifiers are actually both 0xffff, then I guess you're dealing with a prototype device that does not yet have proper USB vendor/device identifiers. You'll want to fix that.

Comment: I've found that to not be the case. My driver specifies the correct, not 0xffff, IDs in the table, but usbhid always grabs it first. I wonder if this is because the driver is not part of the tree (I see a tainted kernel) message in dmesg.

Comment: Have you run `depmod` after installing your module? It updates the `/lib/modules/<kernel_version>/modules.*` files that are used in module loading decisions.

Comment: No I didn't, I'll give that a try.

Comment: `depmod` didn't make a difference :( I'll try to find the source code for similar drivers (probably my logitech unifying receiver) and see if there any fundamental differences.

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, the `insmod` command need only be issued when opening my GUI. I could add some logic before that call to detect the device and unbind manually. There wouldn't be a need for the udev rule.